# Java Spring-Hibernate mapping question?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, join

Say I have domain objects corresponding to `Posts` and `Users`.  Nevertheless, I have corresponding database tables containing information relevant to "posts" and "users".

Currently I have properly set up the mapping in Hibernate so that I can pull the info from the "posts" table and save it as a `Post` object.  However, I then added to my `Posts` domain object, a reference to a `User` object (so that each post can have a corresponding `User` object).

In my database structure, the "posts" table has a `user_id` column which is a foreign key into the "users" table.

My question is: when querying the "posts" table in my DAO, do I have to join on the "users" table and then somehow cast the returned user data into a `User` object?  Or can I simply leave my query as it is (i.e. just querying the "posts" table), and somehow add a hibernate mapping so that the `User` attribute in the `Posts` table gets populated? (I guess I am wondering if Hibernate can automatically generate the join for me if I set up the mapping properly - examples would be great too!)

Thanks, and I hope I was clear enough.

**Update**: Just to clarify, here are some code snippets:

My Post Object:

```
public class Posts {

  private String title;
  ...
  private User user;

  //getters and setters here
}
```

My Post table columns:

```
post_id (primary key)
title
...
user_id (foreign key into User table)
```

My mapping (without taking into account the User attribute) currently looks like this:

```
<class name="com...Post" table="post">
    <id name="pId" column="post_id" />
    <property name="title" column="title" type="java.lang.String" />
    ...
            <!-- Need to add mapping here to join with user table?? -->
</class>
```

So basically, my DAO currently fetches a Post object without the `private User user` attribute (since I just added this).  My question was how do I populate that attribute in the Post object (**so that the fetched Post object also contains a User object**)?

Sorry if the current posts already answered this...they were just slightly confusing to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Well, you got a confusing answer first because you asked a confusing question... The answer to your renewed question is indeed to define a many to one mapping for your Post class (as others have already mentioned). Now, if you want to fetch the whole stuff with a single join query, you write:

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="User" column="user_id" fetch="join" />
```

Original post:

By default, Hibernate fetches lazily. In fact, you need to touch the `lazy` property only if you want eager fetching. Rough example for the behaviour of the default lazy fetch plan:

```
Post post = (Post) session.load(Post.class, new Long(123));
// at this point, post refers to a proxy object created by Hibernate
// in the background - no post or user data has been loaded from DB
post.getId();
// post still refers to the proxy object
User user = post.getUser();
// post is now loaded, but user not - it refers to a proxy object
String name = user.getName(); // Now the user data is loaded from DB
```

So if you are happy with multiple queries, you don't need to do anything special. OTOH if you want to fetch all post and user data in a join query, you need to set the attribute `fetch="join" in your mapping for the`user` property.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you're looking for the many-to-one mapping (many Posts to one User). Add the following to your mapping for the Post object:

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="User" column="user_id" lazy="false" />
```

Comment: Agree to above answer. The mapping is necessary to fetch User record.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that by using the lazy property which is not activated by default.
See some examples here http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html

Comment: Lazy fetching is the default behaviour - as stated even in the article you linked.